# Strange behavior of MVVM binding to property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am beginner in MVVM. I am writing simple app called Members. This is my member class (model):

```
class Member: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Member(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        _infoCommand = new InfoCommand(this);
    }

    string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            _name= value;
            notify("Name");
            notify("CanShowInfo");
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void notify(string property_name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property_name));
        }
    }

    private ICommand _infoCommand;
    public ICommand InfoCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _infoCommand;
        }
        set
        {
            _infoCommand = value;
        }
    }

    public bool CanShowInfo
    {
        get
        {
            return _infoCommand.CanExecute(null);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my InfoCommand class:

```
class InfoCommand : ICommand
{
    Member _member;

    public InfoCommand(Member member)
    {
        _member = member;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_member.Jmeno.Length > 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("I am " + _member.Name);
    }
}
```

This is my MemberViewModel class:

```
class MembersViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ObservableCollection<Member> _members = new ObservableCollection<Member>();

    public MembersViewModel()
    {
        Members.Add(new Member("Member1"));
        Members.Add(new Member("Member2"));
        Members.Add(new Member("Member3"));
        Members.Add(new Member("Member4"));
        Members.Add(new Member("Member5"));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void notify(string property_name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property_name));
    }

    Member _selectedMember;

    public Member SelectedMember
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedMember;
        }

        set
        {
            _selectedMember= value;
            notify("SelectedMember");
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Member> Members
    {
        get
        {
            return _members;
        }
        set
        {
            _members = value;
        }
    }

    AddCommand _addCommand;

    public AddCommand AddCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_addCommand == null)
                _addCommand = new AddCommand(this);
            return _addCommand;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my AddCommand:

class AddCommand : ICommand
    {
        MembersViewModel _vm;

```
    public AddCommand(MembersViewModel vm)
    {
        _vm = vm;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _vm.Members.Add(new Member("New Member")); //<-------------------------
    }
}
```

And finally my View:

```
<Window x:Class="mvvm_gabriel.View.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:mvvm_gabriel.ViewModel"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="482" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModels:MembersViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Members}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMember, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Info" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Command="{Binding InfoCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=CanShowInfo, Mode=OneWay}" />

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedMember.Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <Button Content="Add" Command="{Binding AddCommand}" />
</Grid>
```

When I click some member in my ListView, his name is shown in TextBox. Now I can edit this name and property of my Member object is updated automatically. When I delete name of some member completely (string.Length == 0), Info button in my member template is disabled.

I can also add new members by clicking Add button. Member is added to my observable collection and automatically shown in ListView.

Everything works perfectly as far as here.

But now: look at line marked like this `<----------------------` in my AddCommand.Execute method. When I add new member to my collection, I automatically give him name "New Member" and everything works fine. I can then adit my member's name and my button is disabled automatically as described above. But when I give empty string as the name for new member in constructor on marked line, enabling of my Info button quits working. I can give my new member any name and my Info button is still disabled.

Can anyone explain it and suggest some solution, please?

Comment: `CanExecute` of commands also require notification when condition inside it is changed. You aren't rising it anywhere, so view will never update button. Add to name setter something to rise `CanExecuteChanged` event.

Comment: You don't need to specify the enabled property on your button, it will pick up from `CanExecute` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button in the mainwindow is binding the IsEnabled of the button to a property in the model, but the command binding will also cause the button to interrogate the CanExecute() of the command.

```
<Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Info" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Command="{Binding InfoCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=CanShowInfo, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

This can lead to confusing behavior, as seen in your case.

You can basically remove the IsEnabled binding of the button, and add the property changed handler to the InfoCommand.

```
public class InfoCommand : ICommand
{
    Member _member;

    public InfoCommand(Member member)
    {
        _member = member;
        _member.PropertyChanged += _member_PropertyChanged;
    }

    private void _member_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "Name")
            RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }

    private void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
            CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_member.Name.Length > 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("I am " + _member.Name);
    }
}
```